How to think about phrasing in rhythm exercises?
I have the following exercise, which I am practicing on the piano by counting the beats, and playing a root note on my left hand and a fifth on my right so that I can hear I’m holding the notes their full length and getting the rests right:

We have the marked phrase and it’s clear that the two parts are made of two identical phrases, shifted by one measure.
In general, when I practice reading rhythm, I find it easiest to think “vertically” (what’s the coordination that needs to happen between my hands next), but I suspect this makes me lose the sense of the phrase.
How do you think about your phrasing when you practice rhythm?

It seems you're asking about personal opinions, and such questions are normally discouraged/frowned upon on this site (as most StackExchange network sites). There are many ways one may "think" phrasings in a situation like this (vertically, horizontally, concurrently, etc.), and even many more in more complex situations: for instance, where there is a relation, but the phrases are not identical, not to mention the fact that a rhythmically identical phrase may be harmonically very different. There's no absolute choice or "best practice" for things like these.

Respectfully, I disagree. I am not asking about opinions, I am asking about 1. what does phrasing mean in the context of a purely rhythmic exercise (it’s clearly marked, but there are no pitches to work with -  now what?), and 2. cognitive strategies for dealing with it.

Having a clear mental 'image' of what it ought to sound like to the (internal) ear, or feel like in your hands, is very helpful. Of course, this hopes you already have a recording or some way of already knowing how it should be played.

Your image looks like a published source. Does it say anything in text about the imitative aspect of the rhythm?

@musicamante, other than the ending measure, how are the two parts not rhythmically identical?

@MichaelCurtis The OP only made an example, they're asking about [possible] "exercises", and, by extension, querying about general/common practices when dealing with similar (or not) situations. Even with this is relatively simple example, there can be many different interpretations of its phrasing: for instance, one could choose to follow a leading part, or even have two very distinct phrasings until the end, or in the first 8 (considering the relevance of approaching a conclusion), and even in the first 7/6 bars only, since bar 7 is the first homo-rhythmic one.

@HNHN As written in my reply to Michael Curtis, even with rhythmic relations there is no absolute "best choice". Even though melody lines may partially clarify and enforce phrasing relations within a possible ensemble, voice phrasings may have different levels, possibly considering the phrasing within each voice and within the ensemble and still open to personal taste. Besides, this is a rhythm exercise, so phrasing could only be expressed with variable dynamics or pitch (if allowed) unless you consider much more complex matters: it's perfectly reasonable to use distinct phrasings for each »

@HNHN » voice, but it's also important to consider temporal relations and meaning within the overall musical structure. For instance, the rhythm coincidence of the seventh bar may be important, but mostly because we're approaching the end: not only of the phrase, but of the piece itself. In a case like this, the phrasing of each voice may begin to change as a group, because that "coincidence" could highlight an important step towards a relevant point within the piece. If that happened in less relevant point, it could have been highlighted as well, but separate phrasing could be restored back.

@musicamante, so when you wrote "...but the phrases are not identical..." you were not referring specifically to the example the OP posted? That is a very strange way to word a comment about exercises generally. Also, in your comments you talk about "best choice", but the OP did not ask for a best choice.

@MichaelCurtis Yes, I was indeed referring to possible cases, not just the one at hand. The OP is asking "How do you think about your phrasing when you practice rhythm?", which is a broader question, and I only said that there is no absolute best practice, meaning that there are many ways to consider phrasing, so one cannot just answer generically about how they "think about phrasing when practising rhythm", as any case is different, and while some aspects and considerations can be common, each situation may require very different strategies depending on the context.

I’m starting to think the concept of phrasing in this context may be too advanced for my current musical development phase. I’ll just ignore the phrases and return to them in a couple of years.

Just to be clear about the notation, the long arching line over the notes in LH m. 1 to the first beat of m. 4, and its imitation in RH m.2 to the first beat of m. 5, is called a slur, and indicates notes to be played in a single phrase. The basic execution of a slurred phrase is to play all the notes in an unbroken legato manner.
However, notice there is a rest in the middle of that slurred phrase. Obviously, you can't play a completely "unbroken" line with the rest dividing the phrase. So, the idea of slurred phrases, and unbroken legato, is open to some performance interpretation.
Notice that the remaining measures have no slurs. Unless there is text with the exercises suggesting some other approach, you can regard the absence of slurs to give you latitude about how to phrase the remaining bars. There is no completely objective way to decide the phrasing, but you could use the slurred length as a queue and continue with phrase of about 2-3 measures. Like this...

2-4 measures length is common for phrases so those lengths are a sort of "safe" option.
The imitative aspect of the LH and RH brings in an interesting consideration. Imitation between parts is a common device in contrapuntal music. This rhythm exercise may have the aim of training contrapuntal rhythm. In contrapuntal music independence of parts is important for both composition and performance. Parts are written with musical independence and also performance should somehow highlight independence in execution.
This is where your comment about...

...when I practice reading rhythm, I find it easiest to think
“vertically” (what’s the coordination that needs to happen between my
hands next)...

...deserves some attention.
I think I understand your comment. A term used to describe the rhythmic coordination of the two hands, the rhythmic combination of both hands, is called composite rhythm. It can be explained with a portion of your example exercise...

In that portion there is a mix of eighth notes and quarter notes. There is some "space" with the lines of each part. But, when you put both parts together you have a steady flow of all eighth notes. One way to coordinate the rhythm of that portion is to think about the LH/RH sequence of eighth notes where you can alternate left/right to get the rhythms coordinated. While that can help a lot, it can lead to a sort of "vertical" thinking, and you may not really get the flow of each separate line. That could potentially undermine good execution of contrapuntal lines where you really want the separate parts to be hear as separate and not blended into a homogenous vertical sound.
Of course the two parts do combine vertically. That does happen in reality. So there is a bit of a conundrum to figure out how to achieve the independent execution of the two parts. In terms of composition the basic elements of contrapuntal independence are differences of pitch and rhythm between parts. In performance you can extend that with independence of things like dynamics or articulation.
You could "shape" the phrasing of the separate parts with some crescendo or maybe a bit of a detached articulation. When the parts are combined that would mean while one hand is playing, for example, a bit louder the other remains comparatively softer. Or while one hand plays slightly detached, the other plays legato. Those dynamic and articulation contrasts should help make the parts sound as independent parts. They can also help with the general phrasing. Choices like a bit of accent to start a phrase, a bit of detachment at the end, can help demarcate phrases.
Playing with independent hands in this way requires finesse and is not easy. You can approach it in stages. Play each of the hands separately, but with good phrasing and dynamics/articulation. Play one hand legato and the other detached. Play one hand soft and the other strong. Then flip the roles of the hands. After you can do that, start adding the dynamics/articulations to specific moments in the exercise.
It may seem I have gone far afield from a rhythm exercises getting into too much expressive performance detail. But I think good expressive playing is the key to good phrasing. So, if phrasing is part of the rhythm exercises, expressive playing needs to be embraced to some degree.

I’m starting to think the concept of phrasing in this context may be too advanced for my current musical development phase. I’ll just ignore the phrases and return to them in a couple of years.

I'm not sure that's the best idea. I think a lot of performance teaching encourages playing "musically", playing expressively (with thoughtful and expressive dynamic/articulation) right from the start. You might need to back up to some simpler rhythm exercises or focus on playing hands separately. It is probably better to play expressively from the start instead not and then needing to rehabilitate bad performance habits later on.

Thank you, this is what I was looking for :)

There’s plenty of good (and relevant) information in this answer, but I’m not convinced these phrase marks are intended to indicate slurs.

@ElementsInSpace, yes, but without some text from the source, I don't know what else they might mean. Also, it's not clear if the exercise is meant for particular instruments, but the OP mentioned piano.

Firstly, it certainly is a rhythmic phrase — and quite a good one at that.
The first segment (the question/call) is simply three strong beats.  There’s a brief rest, and then the second segment (the answer/response) is to repeat this but with the preceding off-beats all filled in.  It sounds very much like a complete rhythmic idea; simple but effective.

You say: “it’s clear that the two parts are made of two identical phrases, shifted by one measure”.  But you also say that: “when I practice reading rhythm, I find it easiest to think “vertically”.
If you’re used to only reading the music vertically,
and the phrase marking weren’t written, then there’s a reasonable chance that you wouldn’t have spotted the relationship between the parts.  In other words, I’m guessing that the phrase marks are just there to make that shift extra clear.
It’s worth noting that only the first phrase is marked.  I suggest that this is because once you realise the pattern, restating it would be redundant.

Yes, I definitely wouldn’t have noticed the phrases if they weren’t marked, and it took me a while to notice the mark to :) My follow up question would be: when you read it, do you auralize two shifted phrases in your mind? For instance, if I gave you a phrase and asked that you play it with both hands shifted by a bar - would your strategy be to imagine what that would sound like, and play what you hear inside your mind?
